# Is it possible to access a GATT (Generic Attribute Profile) Bluetooth device using Windows 7?

Tags: generics, attributes, bluetooth, profile

I have a low power RF bluetooth device that requires to be accessed using a GATT interface (Generic Attribute Profile). I have found examples for Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012.

I run Visual Studio 2010.

Could someone either describe how to access a GATT device (using C++ or C#) and/or point to examples on how to access such devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reading your text, I assume you want to make a Bluetooth connection within a normal Windows PC application.

By my knowledge, Windows does not allow Bluetooth connections that way, with exception of Windows 8.1 apps for the Windows Store.
These apps can also run on a PC, so the best thing to do is to implement your idea as an app.

Problems will arise when you want to integrate Bluetooth into an existing application, as Windows applications and Windows 8.1 apps are not compatible with each other due to differences in their libraries.